# What is tzcorrection in php?

Tags: php, date

what is tzcorrection in date? how can we use it? I know it is using in soap time formate. but can't find the meaning of that part.?

> SOAP  YY "-" MM "-" DD "T" HH ":" II ":" SS frac
>   tzcorrection? "2008-07-01T22:35:17.02", "2008-07-01T22:35:17.03+08:00"

I search everywhere but can't find good document or example of it.

Comment: I think it means "time zone correction".

Comment: @mega6382 … Aaaaand what does *that* mean?

Comment: I think it shows your timezone in accordance to GMT. E.g. 
`"tzcorrection"` = `"GMT-06:00"`

Comment: With the timestamp given then, it's the bold bit: *2008-07-01T22:35:17.03 **+08:00***